# Variables con navigator.geolocation.WatchPosition

Tags: javascript

Un saludo, Me estoy iniciando en JS, tengo problemas con las dos variables latitud y longitud, las declaro de forma global (ya sea con let o con var) les doy valor en la función mostrarPosicion. Pero no consigo sacar el valor fuera de la función, me aparece como undefined. ¿Qué podría hacer para obtener el valor fuera de la función? Gracias de antemano.

```
var latitud;   
var longitud;
 
function obtenerUbicacion() {
   var parametros = {enabledHighAccuracy: highAccuracy, timeout: timeOut, maximumAge: maxAge}
   navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(mostrarPosicion, mostrarError, parametros);
}

function mostrarPosicion(posicion) {

  latitud = posicion.coords.latitude;
  longitud = posicion.coords.longitude;

  var ubicacion = document.getElementById("ubicacion");
  var miUbicacion = "";

  miUbicacion += " Latitud: " + latitud + calculaGrados(latitud, "Lat") + " Longitud: " + longitud + calculaGrados(longitud, "Long") + " </br> Margen de error: " + posicion.coords.accuracy + " m.";
  ubicacion.innerHTML = miUbicacion;
}
```

Comment: "No consigo sacar el valor fuera de la función, me aparece como undefined": Debés retornar el valor en la función (¿conocés `return`?). Por cierto, leé [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Hola Jose Maria, bienvenido, en principio tu código parece estar bien, lo que me lleva a preguntar si en el **html** tienes un elemento con **id="ubicacion"** (o tienes varios con igual **id**, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregarlo?, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Si, ya probé con return, sin suerte. El caso es que las coordenadas me las muestra bien, el problema se encuentra cuando intento leer las variables latitud y longitud fuera de la función. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado. la variable latitud y longitud las intentaba usar en una función para representarla en el mapa, tanto la función mostrarPosicion() como verMapa() eran llamadas con un window.addEventListener cada una. Ahora realizo la llamada a la funcion verMapa desde dentro de mostrarPosicion, por lo que las variables son leidas sin problemas.